# Is there a way to configure external module mocks in karma.config.js for testing in angular apps?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, single-spa-angular

I have a micro frontend module i.e. **utility** that is getting imported in another microfrontend **admin-console**. Now the application runs absolutely fine... but when I run the test cases it, it gives error that utility module was not found.
The solution that we got was to add mock for these external modules in the test setup but I am not able to find the write way to include the mock in karma.config.js to achieve this.

**Note:** We are using single-spa for creating the microfrontend architecture.

Below is my mock file code

```
const userPreferencesHandler = {
    changeSelectedLang: () => {},
    changeSelectedTheme: () => {},
    subscribeToLangChange: () => {},
    subscribeToThemeChange: () => {},
};

export default userPreferencesHandler;
```

and this is how I have tried adding in karma.config.js

```
reporters: ["coverage", "progress", "kjhtml"],
     module: {
        exports: {
            '@org/utility': require("path").join(__dirname, "../tests/__mocks__/utility.mocks.ts")
        },
     },
```

I expect the test cases to run successfully using the mocks defined above.